# Javascript ES6 addEventListener inside Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-events, es6-class

I am learning ES6 and I don't understand why my addEventListener not working (trigger only one time) when I use a function like this :

```
// Trigger only one time
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll() );
```

But when I do this :

```
// working !!
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
    let top = window.pageYOffset;

    console.log(top + " vs " + this.offsetTop)

    if (top >= this.offsetTop) {
        this.el.classList.add('is-sticky');
    } else {
        this.el.classList.remove('is-sticky');
    }

});
```

The full code can be find here : https://codepen.io/paallaire/pen/GQLzmg/?editors=0010#0

Comment: In `foo(bar())`, `bar` is always **called first** and its return value is passed to `foo`. `addEventListener` expects to be passed a function, you are passing the *return value* of `this.scroll()` (which is not a function).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The statement:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll() );
```

Binds to the event the result of `this.scroll()`, which is a function call. Such invocation returns `undefined`, because the `scroll` method has no `return` statement:

```
scroll() {
    let top = window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(top + " vs " + this.offsetTop);

    if (top >= this.offsetTop) {
        this.el.classList.add('is-sticky');
    } else {
        this.el.classList.remove('is-sticky');
    }
}
```

## Correct way

**Do NOT use:**

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll);
```

The code above will bind the `this` to `window` when the event triggers.

**The CORRECT** way to use is really:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
   this.scroll();
});
```

Or

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scroll.bind(this));
```

Which, when the event is triggered, will have the code inside `this.scroll` have the `this` point to the current class (`Sticky`) instance.

---

#### Removing the event listener

To remove the event, call [`window.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), but there's a caveat: `removeEventListener` must be called with the exact same argument used in `addEventListener` to remove the listener. In other words, to be able to remove you will have to do:

```
// save the function that will be bound to the event, so you can remove it later
this.scrollBoundFunction = this.scroll.bind(this);
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollBoundFunction);

// and later
window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollBoundFunction);
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but with this technique how I remove the "EventListerner" ?

Comment: You have to call `removeEventListener`, but there is a caveat, check the updated answer.

Comment: While the part about removing the event listener works, I'm curious about why it works in the first place. According to MDN, `function.bind(target)` returns a new function with its `this` set to whatever `target` was. But when providing `this.boundFunction` in `addEventListener`, why doesn't `this.boundFunction` suffer from its own `this` keyword that prefaces it not being bound? Is this some kind of JS optimizarion?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but, the way I see it, `bind` works exactly to override the `this`, returning a function that has its `this` hardcoded (as in it can't be "bound" again) to the `bind` argument. Is that helpful? If not, can you rephrase what you just said?